# When does DFP record impression?

Tags: google-dfp

Does DFP record an impression when ad is visible to the user or when ad is rendered?

I'd like to record impression myself and wonder when I should record it.

Below are the two closest point where I could record impression.

ImpressionViewableEvent (https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsimpressionviewableevent)

SlotRenderEndedEvent (https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsslotrenderendedevent)

Answer (score 0):

It records an impression either as soon as it's rendered or even sooner when it's being requested from DFP. It definitely doesn't wait until the ad is in view.

Answer (score 0):

Once you called .display()

> If single request architecture (SRA) is being used, all impressions
>   are counted upon the first call of the display() function, independent
>   of how many ads actually display on the page.
>
> If non-SRA is used, then an impression is counted for each display()
>   call made on the page.